# OnClickListener good practice

Tags: java, programming-practices, android-development

Which one of the ways has better performance, or  is a good programming practice, making the holder activity extend `OnClickListener` and make a `Switch()` clause for `getItemId()` or making one `OnClickListener` for each one of the buttons or widgets that need it or making separated classes in the same (or another) package that implements `OnClickListener` and instance them in the activity?

Comment: Why don't you measure the performance of both?

Comment: I don't know how to measure it. I have done each one but they seem to be the same...

Comment: Premature optimization, root of all evil, etc.

Comment: Which one do you think will be easier to debug and maintain?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the best and better programming way for to work with button /any other widget

1. Declare Button/ any other widgets Object outside from the Activity life cycle method; mostly after declaration of the public class like this

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   Button button;
2. Always define inside the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method; because it's guaranteed that `onCreate()` always call so therefore it's better to define inside onCreate() method.

Here is the complete Code example

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Any thing you want here
        }
    });



}
```

On the above I have used anonymous class `onClickLListener` that is the nested class of View class; so you can also use separate class
Avoid to make switch statement because it's make your like spaghetti like.